# Why my Armstrong Number Checker Program's 'number' variable changes value at the end?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
number=int(input("Number:"))
number_of_digits=0

list_1 = [int(x) for x in str(number)]

while(number>0):
    number_of_digits=number_of_digits+1
    number=number//10
print("Number Of Digits:",number_of_digits)

new_list = [x ** number_of_digits for x in list_1]

total = 0

for x in new_list:
    total += x
print(list_1)
print(new_list)
print(total)


if (number == total):
    print(number,"Is An Armstrong Number")
else:
    print(number,"Is Not An Armstrong Number")
```

The Output is:

```
Number:1634
Number Of Digits: 4
[1, 6, 3, 4]
[1, 1296, 81, 256]
1634
0 Is Not An Armstrong Number
```

Why it says "0 Is Not An Armstrong Number"
It should say "1634 Is An Armstrong Number"

Comment: Your own code, earlier on, changes `number`: `while(number>0):` ... `number=number//10`. You'll have to assign `number` to another variable _first_ if you still need to refer to it later on.

Comment: Can you show it with a code please?

Comment: Thanks, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should add new variable. Try out this code:

```
number=int(input("Number:"))
number_of_digits=0

list_1 = [int(x) for x in str(number)]

buf = number # assign number to another variable 

while(buf>0):
    number_of_digits=number_of_digits+1
    buf=buf//10
print("Number Of Digits:",number_of_digits)

new_list = [x ** number_of_digits for x in list_1]

total = 0

for x in new_list:
    total += x
print(list_1)
print(new_list)
print(total)


if (number == total):
    print(number,"Is An Armstrong Number")
else:
    print(number,"Is Not An Armstrong Number")
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you divide `number` in your while loop until it becomes `0`. A simple solution will be to copy the value of `number` to a new variable. I've done this with `number_copy`:

```
number=int(input("Number:"))
number_copy = number
number_of_digits=0

list_1 = [int(x) for x in str(number)]

while(number_copy>0):
    number_of_digits=number_of_digits+1
    number_copy=number_copy//10
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it like this before you say but again thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
number=int(input("Number:"))
number_of_digits=0
temporary_number=number

list_1 = [int(x) for x in str(temporary_number)]

while(temporary_number>0):
    number_of_digits=number_of_digits+1
    temporary_number=temporary_number//10

new_list = [x ** number_of_digits for x in list_1]

total = 0

for x in new_list:
    total += x

if (number == total):
    print(number,"Is An Armstrong Number")
else:
    print(number,"Is Not An Armstrong Number")
```

Thanks for everyone!